# how to delete some characters from string php

Tags: php, string, pointers, position, seek

A string contains some characters that needs to be deleted.
`$a = "abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvwxyz";`
I want to delete 5,6,7,8th character from the text. every time characters are shuffled. and i want to delete those characters which are placed at 5th to 8th position

Comment: http://php.net/substr, or maybe http://php.net/substr_replace

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
$new_string = substr($a, 0, 4) . substr($a, 8);
```

or, as say @MarcB, you can use `substr_replace`

```
$new_string = substr_replace($a, '', 4, 4);
```